# Ask for a linq to manipulate arrays of array

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, linq-to-objects

I have an array containing following elements

```
{Mark=90, Students={"Tom","Marry","Jack"}},
{Mark=50, Students={"Niko","Gary","David"}},
{Mark=70, Students={"John","Andy","Amy"}}
```

I want a Linq sentence to convert them to

```
{Mark=90, name="Tom"},
{Mark=90, name="Marry"},
{Mark=90, name="Jack"},
{Mark=50, name="Niko"},
{Mark=50, name="Gary"},
{Mark=50, name="David"},
{Mark=70, name="John"},
{Mark=70, name="Andy"},
{Mark=70, name="Amy"}
```

How could I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could project to an anonymous class (or a real class if you need the sequence outside of your current method):

```
var results = from x in myArray
              from s in x.Students
              select new { x.Mark, name = s };
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `SelectMany`:

```
data.SelectMany(
    item => Students.Select(
        student => new {Mark = item.Mark, name=student.Name}
    )
);
```